# IF in MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Trying to create MySql trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER updVisible AFTER UPDATE ON photos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Status = 2 THEN
        UPDATE otherTable SET IsVisible=0 WHERE PID=NEW.PID
    END IF;
END;
```

But I got error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'END IF' at
>   line 6

MySQL version: 5.1.41-community
What am I doing wrong?

UPD1. This doesn't help

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER updVisible AFTER UPDATE ON photos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Status = 2 THEN
        UPDATE otherTable SET IsVisible=0 WHERE PID=NEW.PID
    END IF
END//
DELIMETER ;
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'END IF END' at line 6

I have root access and using MySql Workbench 5.2.31 CE

Comment: `DELIMETER ;` should be `DELIMITER ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in my machine!

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER test1 AFTER UPDATE ON test
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->     IF NEW.itemId = '2' THEN
    ->         UPDATE test1 SET col1=0 WHERE col2=NEW.`value`;
    ->     END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> DELIMiTER ;
mysql> desc test;
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| itemId | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| key    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| value  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc test1;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a missing semicolon

```
PID=NEW.PID;
```

Comment: Tried ';', and '//' - same error

Comment: This answer actually explains the problem, should have more upvotes

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, you can create the trigger in the SQL window.

You may have to set the delimieter to something like `$$` instead of the default `;`. You can change this easily from the bottom of the SQL window.

In addition, make sure you close your trigger block with the `END` command-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `tutorial`.`before_delete_carts`  
     BEFORE DELETE ON `trigger_carts` FOR EACH ROW  
     BEGIN  
         DELETE FROM trigger_cart_items WHERE OLD.cart_id = cart_id;  
     END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

U have to some syntex problem ..use like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER updVisible AFTER UPDATE ON photos
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Status = 2 THEN
        UPDATE otherTable SET IsVisible=0 WHERE PID=NEW.PID
    END IF
END//
```

Comment: BTW, you seem to **forget to declare `DELIMITER //`.**

Comment: Added DELIMETER //, but I got same error:  

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF
END' at line 6

Comment: @Lari13 lari-man, use `DELIMITER //` before and `DELIMITER ;` after the code written above.

Comment: Not helped :( Updated my question